# Remove node from XML Document

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

```
<Address>
    <value xsi:type="..." xmlns:ns3="..." xmlns:xsi="....">
        <item>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <City>New York</City>
            <Street>Sunrise Av.</Street>
            <Number>164</Number>
        </item>
    </value>
</Address>
<University>
    <value xsi:type="..." xmlns:ns3="..." xmlns:xsi="....">
        <item>
            <Name>Cambridge</Name>
            <Location>UK</Location>
            <Department>IT</Department>
        </item>
    </value>
</University>
<Work>
    <value xsi:type="..." xmlns:ns3="..." xmlns:xsi="....">
</Work>
```

I have the above XML stored in a Java String. I want to remove the `<value>` tag from all of the nodes. Do you have any solution as to how I can do this?

The result that I want is as follows:

```
<Address>
    <item>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <City>New York</City>
        <Street>Sunrise Av.</Street>
        <Number>164</Number>
    </item>
</Address>
<University>
    <item>
        <Name>Cambridge</Name>
        <Location>UK</Location>
        <Department>IT</Department>
    </item>
</University>
<Work>
</Work>
```

Comment: I can think of two ways: 1) Parse it to DOM, remove the elements, and write it back out. 2) Send it through an XSLT transformation that filters out the elements.

Comment: remove the tag? or remove everything enclosed by that tag including the tag?

Comment: I want to remove only the tag. Everything which is enclosed by the tag should exists. For example, <item> tags should not be removed.

Comment: I have generated the XML using JAXBContext and Marshaller. Is there a way that I can use them to remove the <value> tag as is shown in the example above?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a snippet based on XPath and VTD-XML

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;
public class removeTag {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws VTDException,IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        AutoPilot ap=new AutoPilot();
        ap.selectXPath("//value");
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\tag.xml", false)){
            System.out.println("error in xml");
            return;
        }
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        xm.bind(vn);
        ap.bind(vn);
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            xm.remove();//remove value fragment     
            long l = vn.getContentFragment(); //replace value with everything it encloses
            xm.insertBeforeElement(vn.getXML().getBytes(), l);
        }
        xm.output("d:\\xml\\newTag.xml");
    }
}
```